# Young diagrams in Latex - large strips and braces

Tags: math, latex, combinatorics

I am trying to write a few properties of Young diagrams using Latex and am trying to make the symbolic notation as clear as possible but I encountered a few problems.

I would like to study functions whose arguments are Young diagrams, for example long vertical or horizontal strips. I would like to draw a vertical strip by drawing 2-3 blocks at the top, followed by vertical dots and finishing with a single block at the bottom, all in a brace to the left (or right) saying that there are k blocks.

I tried using the `\young` environment but it doesn't seem to let me skip vertical strips or draw empty blocks. the `ytableau` environment does, but I don't know how to insert the dots in the place of the skipped blocks. Also, when considering a function of two arguments, the `ytableau` environment kinda messes up the centering and gives the top block as the center of the line, which doesn't look good... Also, in the later stages I plan to distinguish between the first few blocks and so would like to put into a brace only a few of the first (or the last) blocks.

To give it a more visual explanation, this is something I would like:
[image: To give it a more visual explanation, this is something I would like]

And the best I got so far is this:

[image: And the best I got so far is this]

I would really appreciate all the help and suggestions.

Comment: There's also a dedicated [LaTex site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) here on StackExchange.